# Proper preposition in 'Are you busy coming week?'

Tags: prepositions

When I make a sentence:

> Are you busy coming week?

which preposition should I put between *busy* and *coming week*?

Comment: I would say, "Are you busy this coming week?"   or "Are you busy in the coming week?"  Let's see what other answers there are.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I think you've pretty much covered the good answers.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK has given the most likely answers.  You could also put '...over the...', '...during the...', '...throughout the...'.  Note that these alternatives are not synonyms.  Most carry slightly different nuances.